# Incremental loading from Hadoop to Hive in Informatica

Tags: hadoop, hive, etl, data-warehouse, informatica

I have a plain file in Hadoop and I need to load this file to Informatica by incrementing and saving data in Hive. How can I do it? And how can I create incremental loading (SCD1)?

Comment: Have you already tried to handle this problem in some way? By describing that you can significantly help other people to answer your question.

Comment: citxx, no I haven't.

Comment: dont know about informatica but you can do something like  with simple load command  you can load file to hive and ,scheduling the load command with crontabs or oozie. Every time pass the new file to load command.

Comment: Do you have PowerCenter Big Data Edition (BDE)? What version of Hive is installed in the cluster?

Comment: sravan, thank you for idea, i will read about crontabs and oozie.

Comment: Marek Grzenkowicz , hive ver. 0.13; I don't have BDE. But how can BDE help me?